# SQL Join combine two columns into one

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join 4 tables.  I want all the data from table A.  Table A, B, C are linked by Name column. Table B,C,D all have an ID column.  Table B calls it HostID.  Table C and D call it ObjectID.  I created two joins for this ID like this:

```
Left Join D on B.HostID = D.ObjectID
Left Join D on C.ObjectID = D.ObjectID
```

My query contains a column for HostID and ObjectID. How can I get only one column?

Here's what the data looks like now. Value comes from a fifth table that I didn't mention above.  the value table is linked on HostID or ObjectID

```
Name - HostID -  ObjectID - Value
Smith -  123  -   Null  -    7
Jones -  Null -   456   -    3
```

Here's what I want it to look like

```
Name  -  ObjID - Value
Smith -   123  -   7
Jones  -  456  -   3
```

Comment: Take the column you don't want out of the select clause.

Comment: for every row one column has the correct data and the other is null

Comment: does the same column always have the correct data?

Comment: Those tables are linked by "Name" column or "ID" column? Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: They are linked by both.  I'm taking all the data from table A and linking tables b and C by name.  Table D is linked to B and C by ObjectID. Table D doesn't have Name and Table A doesn't have ObjectID.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to pull whichever value is not null.  You can also use `concatenate`:

```
Select Name, ISNULL(HostID, ObjectID) as ObjID, Value

From A 
Left Join B on A.Name = B.Name 
Left Join C on A.Name = C.Name 
Left Join D on ISNULL(B.HostID, C.ObjectID) = D.ObjectID 
Left Join E on D.ObjectID = E.ObjectID
```

`ISNULL` will return `HostID`, unless `HostID` is null, in which case it will return `ObjectID`.

Comment: My overall goal is to get Value.  I'm only getting values for items in table C.  Here's my Join:

Comment: My overall goal is to get Value.  I'm only getting values for items in table C.  Here's my joins:  From A Left Join B on A.Name = B.name Left Join C on A.name = C.Name Left Join D on C.HostID = D.ObjectID Left Join E on D.ObjectID = E.ObjectID  ... If I could join the new ObjID that you created in the select statement to D.Object I think it would work.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can add the same `isnull` logic in your join.  I'll edit the answer to add an example.

Comment: @jbw1897 - see edits above.  You may need to add the `isnull` to the join to E as well - it isn't clear to me why you are joining through D.  Did this work to solve your problem?